# The current I=-10e^-2t,Find the voltage of the source Vs?

Tags: circuit-analysis, signal-processing, passive-networks, laplace-transform

> This is the Question

[image]

**Attempt:**

I Solved this circuit with two different method like this

[image]

> Now In the laplace transformation method I am getting an extra term that is first derivation of impulse(doublet).
>
> Now why is there discrepancy in this two method? What is the mistake i am doing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In using 1/s for the capacitor, you've forgotten about initial conditions.

At t=0 the voltage across the capacitor is -10V. Either that voltage has been generated by V(s) (unlikely, if not impossible), or the capacitor has an initial condition of -10V. Try including this in your Laplace formulation.

In this problem you have been told the I.C. implicitly by being given the current through R, and consequently the voltage across C, so the I.C. is already taken care of in the differential equation solution.

Comment: ....Thanks alot sir. You are genius......i got the answer after putting the I.C but there will be I.C for inductor too that is 10A